# Class of all sigma fields that contain $\mathbf{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to find the class of all sigma fields that contain $\mathbf{C}$.
I want to know if my work is correct or no. Or is a better way possible?(sorry not native English)

[image]

**a)**$\Omega=\{0,1\}$ and $C=\{ \{0\}\}$
I think there is only one possible sigma field.
$$\sigma_1=\{\emptyset ,\Omega, \{0\} , \{1\} \}$$

**b)**$\Omega=\{0,1,2\}$ and $C=\{ \{0\}\}$

I think if I make  a partition on $\Omega$ like
 $$D=\{A_1,\cdots,A_k \}$$ so 
the sigma field generated by $D$ is $$\{\emptyset ,\Omega,all \,  \, A_i , all \, A_i\cup A_j 
, all \, A_i\cup A_j\cup A_k , \cdots \}$$

So if I want to generate all sigma fields that contain $C=\{\{0\}\}$
It is only enough to make different partition on $\Omega$ that $\{0\}$ is one of those partition. 
  So two partitions on $\Omega$
are possible:
$$\{ \{0 \}  , \{1,2 \}  \} $$
$$\{ \{0 \}  , \{1\},\{2 \}  \} $$

$$\sigma_1=\sigma \bigg(  \{ \{0 \}  , \{1,2 \}  \}\bigg)$$(When $\sigma(C)$ is sigma field generated by $C$)
$$\sigma_2=\sigma \bigg(  \{ \{0 \}  , \{1\},\{2 \}  \} \bigg)$$

I think,until now, This is work for $C=\{A \}$ that $A$ is a singleton event.

**c)** $\Omega=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $C=\{ \{0,1\}\}$
$$C_1=\{ \{0,1\}  ,  \{ 2,3,4 \} \} $$
$$C_2=\{ \{0,1\}  , \{ 2\}, \{ 3,4 \}  \} $$
$$C_3=\{ \{0,1\}  , \{ 3 \}, \{ 2,4 \}  \} $$
$$C_4=\{ \{0,1\}  ,  \{ 4 \}, \{ 2,3 \} \} $$

so all sigma fields are $\sigma(C_1),\sigma(C_2),\sigma(C_3),\sigma(C_4)$.

Edit: Tnx to @Berici, 
Since $A=\{0,1\}$ could be generate by $\{0\} \cup\{1 \}$
so It contains following case too.
$$C_5=\{ \{0\},\{1\}  ,  \{ 2,3,4 \} \} $$
$$C_6=\{ \{0\},\{1\}  , \{ 2\}, \{ 3,4 \}  \} $$
$$C_7=\{ \{0\},\{1\}  , \{ 3 \}, \{ 2,4 \}  \} $$
$$C_8=\{ \{0\},\{1\} ,  \{ 4 \}, \{ 2,3 \} \} $$
$$C_9=\{ \{0\},\{1\} , \{ 2\} ,\{3 \}, \{ 4 \}  \} $$

**d)** If $\Omega=\{a_1,\cdots a_n \}$ has $n$ elements what is the number of all partition on $\Omega$ (It is useful to find , number of all generated sigma  fields )

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Source of question: A Probability Path, Sidney I. Resnick page 20

Comment: @Jean Marie, Thank you for edit.

Comment: For c), we can double the number by considering $\{0\},\,\{1\}$ in place of $\{0,1\}$, and the partition $\{0,1\}, \{2\},\{3\},\{4\}$ is missing. Also note that a $\sigma$-algebra over a finite base set is just a *Boolean algebra*.

Comment: @Berci, You right. so I should change it a little.